# Is there a single-word equivalent for "to approach for help"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For stylistic reasons, I am looking for a transitive verb, which could be used as a substitute for "approached... for help", as in "In difficult legal circumstances, he [VERB] a solicitor".

Comment: Are you trying to convey the sense that he _sought and found_ a solicitor, merely sought one out, or that he approached a _particular_ solicitor? Did he proceed to consult or retain the solicitor, or just approach one without further action?

Comment: @Celery Man You rightly identify the need for further detail. In my scenario, the subject realised that he was in difficulty and approached a solicitor he knew for help. No formal retainer was intended or resulted and it is the initial approach (rather than any subsequent dealings) which I need to describe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"He [**consulted**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consult) a solicitor":

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 Seek information or advice from (someone with expertise in a particular area):
>
> *you should consult a financial advisor*
>
> MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Anyone seeking such advice should consult a competent professional.*
>
> *Do always consult an expert for advice on international adoption agencies and orphanages.*
>
> *Continue to engage and consult professional trainers, breeders and other specialists.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 10):

"***Solicit***" would often do if he was approaching anyone else for services or assistance; but “he solicited a solicitor” won't work.

Comment: But it's exactly the right answer.

Comment: Of course you can solicit a solicitor. It might sound a bit "odd" but it's correct.

Comment: I'm sure many a solicitor has been solicited while walking down certain streets.

Comment: I disagree.  "Solicit" doesn't have "for help" built it.   You have to solicit _for_ something.   "He solicited a solicitor for a do-it-yourself will".  The definition of "Solicit" is "to ask for something".  Not necessarily help.

Answer (score 6):

*Seek*/*sought* might be a possibility:

> 1:  to resort to :  go to
>
> 2 a :  to go in search of :  look for
>
> *The office is seeking a salesperson.*
> *You should seek medical help immediately if you experience any chest pain or shortness of breath.*

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seek))

Comment: Wish I'd thought of that! +1

Answer (score 4):

***Beseeched*** would work.

ask (someone) urgently and fervently to do something; implore; entreat

Answer (score 1):

In that particular sentence, you could say "he *retained* a solicitor."  But that would generally only work for certain professions.

Comment: And only in certain areas, in others "retaining" a solicitor implies keeping them on permanently after the original suit/work is complete.

Answer (score 1):

***Enlist*** can be used as a transitive verb.

> [transitive] if you enlist someone or enlist their help, you ask them to help or support you
>
> [[Macmillan]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enlist)

Example in your context:

> The society has commissioned a land valuation, which is due to be completed this week, and has **enlisted a solicitor** to establish the trust fund.
>
> http://www.guardian-series.co.uk/news/10691829.print/

Answer (score 1):

Supplicate -

> 1:  to ask humbly and earnestly of
>
> 2:  to ask for earnestly and humbly

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Implored Begged Pleaded Beseeched

Answer (score 1):

I believe **asked** works for your example.

Answer (score 1):

How about petition?

From Dictionary.com

> verb (used with object)
>
> > 5. to beg for or request (something).

Comment: "something" not "help".   The OP is asking about petitioning for something specific: help.

Answer (score 1):

How about the word entreated ?

Comment: Can you expand your answer to give a reason why you suggested this word?

Answer (score 0):

I like the word ***Implore*** in this case.

> "In difficult legal circumstances, he implored a solicitor".

Comment: To me, that sentence is incomplete: what did he implore a solicitor to do?